# Center Image with out moving the DIV and Text

Tags: html, css

Im making a text limit Website and want to include a example as an Image, (I want the Image to be in the middle of the screen)
for some reason when i use the image centering code from W3Schools the text and Div's that I used to make the limitation, move to the edge of the site and arent fully visible

I tried this script from W3 Schools

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

the Div and text dont have a CSS script, I'd like them to be on the left of the screen which works without a CSS script

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Please share a fiddle

Comment: @PiyushPranjal No need. SO has the same feature and it displays it embedded in the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

just change your margin-left to

```
img {
   display: block;
   margin-left: 30%;
   width: 40%;
}
```